# Kendo grid mvc with a viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have been struggling with this for a while now, I'm not sure if this is right. But I have a viewmodel with three tables and in my view I'm using the view model. The view has a kendo grid which needs data from one of the tables in the view model, I'm not able to bind the model to the grid. Any leads are appreciated.

ViewModel.cs :

```
 public class AppAccountMappingViewModel
    {
        public virtual List<AppAccountsExternal> AppAccountsExternal { get; set; }
        public virtual List<AppAccountsInternal> AppAccountsInternal { get; set; }
        public virtual AppAccountMapping AppAccountMapping { get; set; }
    }
```

I need a list of AppAccountsInternal to bind it to the grid.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AppAccountsInternal()
{
      var result = new AppAccountMappingViewModel();
         result.AppAccountsInternal= _unitofwork.AppAccountsInternal.GetInternalClients(clientid);
         return View(result);
}
```

View :

```
@model EntityFrameworkClasses.ViewModel.AppAccountMappingViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("AppAccountInternalGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{

    //columns.Bound(p => p.View).Title("View").ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("Index","SaveRec") + "' target='_blank'>View</a>").Width(150);


    columns.Bound(p => p.AppAccountsInternal).Title("Account Internal Name Label1").Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Select(x=>x.AccountInternalNameLabel2)).Title("Account Internal Name Label2").Width(130);

    columns.Bound(p => p.Select(x=>x.AccountInternalNameLabel3)).Title("Account Internal Name Label3").Width(130);

    columns.Bound(p => p.Select(x=>x.AccountInternalNameLabel4)).Title("Account Internal Name Label4").Width(150);

    columns.Bound(p => p.Select(x=>x.AccountsInternalID)).Title("Accounts Internal ID").Width(150);

    columns.Bound(p => p.Select(x=>x.ClientID)).Title("ClientID").Width(150);

})


    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })


     .Groupable()

     .Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
     .Sortable()
     .ColumnMenu()
     .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
     .Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .Ajax()
        .PageSize(50)
        .ServerOperation(false)
    .PageSize(20)


 )

        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                 .Refresh(true)
                .Input(true)
                .Numeric(false)
             )
   .Selectable()

 )
```

I'm making a mistake with the model being binded. What is the right way of doing it? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are bringing an initial load to the grid via your model, you need to remember that the grid reads from an ajax called endpoint (it makes it's own call). Assigning the model to the grid at design time helps in column validation and other things.

You should implement the read method on the grid datasource and then return your collection to the grid in a separate controller method.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(200)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetAppAccountsInternaGridData", "MyController", @Model.clientID))
        .ServerOperation(false)
```

Your controller needs a method to obtain the grid data.

```
using Kendo.Mvc
...
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]        
public ActionResult GetAppAccountsInternaGridData(int clientID, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{ 
     var result = new AppAccountMappingViewModel();
     result.AppAccountsInternal= _unitofwork.AppAccountsInternal.GetInternalClients(clientid);
     return View(result);
     return Json(result.AppAccountsInternal.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to bind to your grid the data from the field AppAccountsInternal ? This can be accomplished easily but I a don't understand what are there values you are trying to show as columns?  This doesn't seem valid. Your class AppAccountsInternal has fields named AccountInternalNameLabel2, AccountInternalNameLabel3 and AccountInternalNameLabel4?
If this is just some example code for your question and I have understood correctly all you have to do is bind the right model to the grid and set your columns right.

If for example the class AppAccountsInternal is of this type:

```
public class AppAccountsInternal 
{
    public string AppAccountsInternal1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AppAccountsInternal2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AppAccountsInternal3 { get; set; }
}
```

your grid should have it's columns like that. Binded to the model.AppAccountsInternal list and have as a name the name of the field.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.AppAccountsInternal )
.Name("AppAccountsInternal ")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.AppAccountsInternal1).Title("Account Internal Name Label1").Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.AppAccountsInternal2).Title("Account Internal Name Label2").Width(130);
    columns.Bound(p => p.AppAccountsInternal3).Title("Account Internal Name Label3").Width(130);
    // more columns
})
```

This is the way to go if you only want to show the data. If you want operations in your grid rows then the case changes a lot. You could submit forms with client input templates or you can use the Kendo CRUD operations but that is for another question.